# Why do we substract 4 from arm926ejs_reset before loading it into sp?

Tags: assembly, arm, startup

I have a startup code for ARM926ej-s which supports ISA ARMv5TEJ. Startup code looks like below, but i switched some commands/data with comments for clarity. Lines which are still unclear to me are marked with a comment "`@???????????????????????????????????????????????????????`".

I wonder, why do we need to substract "`#4`" from value (location of "`arm926ejs_reset`") stored in register "`r3`"? And then load it into a stack pointer 4 lines later, where we are setting the stacks for the first processor mode which is fast interrupt mode.

```
__start:
arm926ejs_reset:

@here there is image header data needed by ISROM

arm926ejs_reset_handler:

    @here we disable MMU, I-cache, D-cache, flush them... and prepare the mcpu.

    LDR   r5, =inVirtMem

    @here we enable MMU.

    MOV   pc, r5 

    NOP
    NOP
    NOP

inVirtMem:
    ADR   r3, arm926ejs_reset @load location of "arm926ejs_reset" label in r3
    MOV   r1, #IF_MASK

    SUB   r3, r3, #4 @???????????????????????????????????????????????????????

    ORR   r0, r1, #MODE_FIQ
    MSR   cpsr_cxsf, r0
    MOV   sp, r3 @???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
    SUB   r3, r3, #FIQ_STACK_SIZE

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar startup codes as yours on the net which have their code well commented. In this [start up code](http://sw.lpcware.com/?p=swim.git&a=blob&hb=HEAD&f=Phytec_LPC3250/Keil/app/phy3250_startup_entry.s), you can see on `Line 186` that `r3` is pointing to the `MMU` base address. `MMU` spans ahead of its base address. i.e if `MMU_BASE_ADDRESS`=0x400, `MMU` entries will be at `0x400`, `0x404` `0x408` etc. Now in `Line 217` `r3` is being subtracted by 4 and then assigned to `SP` on `Line 222`. If we don't subtract 4, our first entry of stack ( observe stack is growing in the reverse direction of `MMU` layout ) will overwrite on the first `MMU` entry! Hence the subtraction.

Likewise in your example if we don't subtract 4, **your stack will overwrite on the reset handler itself**. Your program will go for a toss.

One more example is this [start up code](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/lpc3000/message/1134) where they are going to end of `IRAM` and subtracting 4. End of IRAM implies just outside the `IRAM` and hence the subtraction to come inside the `IRAM`

Observe that stack is growing upwards in this particular example( or towards lower addresses ).( ARM stacks can grow in either ways )

Comment: This is only true of an *empty-descending* stack. These are supported in ARM mode, but not Thumb mode (you'd have to have separate store and decrement instructions, which would be a bad thing). Most ARM ABIs use *full-descending* stacks. If course, it's possible that @71GA has an unusual system.

Comment: I have been using 32 bit (ARM) processing and have had no problems so far. In my startup code there is allso an instruction `.code 32` which tells compiler to organize an executable document for an 32 bit (ARM) execution.

Comment: But still in my startup code i am substracting 4 from a label, which is not a MMU base adress.

Comment: See, label is just a marking point. Its for our reference and to the assembler to generate proper addresses but in the binary it would have been converted to an adddress. A label will be pointing to a memory location. In the example I quoted it was pointing to MMU base address, in your example it is pointing to reset handler. Thats the only difference. In either case, writing there would cause loss of info etc

Answer (score 0):

My **guess**: the stack is to be positioned *below* to label (presumably, writing to the label would be a bad thing), so the author though it needed to be adjusted down one one word.

This does seem odd though - normally a stack is using in *full-decending* mode, so the initial value of the stack-pointer is never written to. Unless you can prove otherwise I wouldn't be surprised if this was a (harmless) bug.

It *might* be reserving a word of stack-space for its own use, outside of the snippet you show?

Comment: Stack can grow either ways in ARM. It just depends on whether you want to decrement SP or increment SP.
This is not a bug. This is the proper adjusting of stack top.

Comment: Yes an no. It *can* go either way, but the conventional way is *full-descending* and this is the only supported way in Thumb mode.